# How to write formula in DataGridView in VB?

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, datagridview

I want to create a `DataGridView` with columns like this

```
| Date1... | Date 2.... | J | PR | Total |

|12/20/13 | 02/20/14 | 3  | 50 | 150 |

|12/20/13 | 02/20/14 | 2  | 50 | 100 |

|12/20/13 | 02/20/14 | 1  | 50 | 50 |
```

where:

- Date1, Date2, and PR are write syntax manually

  Date1: 12/20/13, 12/20/13, 12/20/13

  Date2: all of list item are 02/20/14

  PR: all of list item are 50
- J = interval from Date1 to Date2

  From Dec2013 to Feb2013 is 3 times

  From Jan2014 to Feb2014 is 2 times

  From Feb2014 to Feb2014 is 1 times
- Total = PR * J

I don't know what code to use.

Comment: Where are your query or datasource?

Comment: Is the grid bound to a data source or not?  If it is, what is that data source?

Comment: Are you wanting to calculate `J` as well or just `Total`?